# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied WCF

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm using BizTalk server 2010.

I'm using the client certificate where I have imported that in IIS as well as Trusted root certificate store. Im using httpsTransport with customBinding. When I try to browse in BizTalk server with https, I'm able to browse, but in the client side, they are not able to browse and they get

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

Is there anything that needs to be set in BizTalk or the settings should be done at the client end?

Is it related to anti virus that is blocking?

Comment: Are you requiring a certificate to be presented by the client for authentication? or do you not have Certificate Authentication enabled?

Comment: The settings would be in IIS rather than BizTalk, check the settings there that Nick mentioned.

Comment: Hi Nick In IIS the Client certificate is set to Require also in BizTalk receive location I have set that to require. Because i want to work that with require. In BizTalk I'm able to browse the WSDL but in external system there is an issue Access is denied.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you are requiring Client Certificate Authentication when a client attempts to query the web resource, but no certificate is being presented. This is not an anti-virus issue.

You already have the certificate (and Root Authority) on your server which is why you can retrieve the resource successfully from the BizTalk Server.

To resolve this issue on your clients, install the certificate on each client that needs to connect (plus the Root Authority certificate if this is one you have created yourself) - the Client Certificate needs to be placed into the Personal Certificate Store for the user that is attempting to request the resource. Then when you connect from your client, the correct certificate will be presented to the server and Client Certificate Authentication will be performed, resolving your '403 - Access Denied' error.

If you have a large number of clients and you don't want to go through this trouble, simple disable Client Certificate Auth in IIS; your traffic will still be secured through SSL/TLS.